# How do I make a dropdown input field option based on a previous input field insert?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to accomplish the feature that a user can insert a statement in an input field, and that statement will show up as a dropdown option in later fields.

The form needs to be filled out in order so ideally I would like the fields to be grayed out until the previous field is completed.

The first input field would be text, and then the second input field would give a dropdown with two selections: `[Text from first input field]` or `New Statement`

I would like to be able to continue this in other input fields.

So by the third input field, you would have the dropdown choices: `[Text from first input field]`, `[Text from second input field]`, and `New Statement`.

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to link personal websites here, but if it helps to show what I have so far, just ask and I will message it to you.

---

**EDIT:** Here's an image of what I'm talking about.
[image: Progress thus far]

I'd like the `Statement 1` and `Statement 2` options to show the text of what the user has previous entered. Selecting `New Statement` should allow the user to insert a new statement.

Comment: I would recommend you do this with javascript, otherwise you can do it with php with a multi-page form - by submitting the input options and creating the select dropdowns with php for display on the next page.

Comment: give a link or printscreen to understand what you try to do..

Comment: I've added the image

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it using javascript. In your case you only need to collect upper fields values. Generate options from them and put into next select.

Comment: I'm going to give this a try tonight and I'll let you know if it works